# How to get a Signature for a Blob Storage in Windows Azure ?

Tags: azure-storage, blobstorage

https://configuat.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/Motorist/uat/files/ar/es/config_AR_es.json

This is my web service address.
As a read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx) there is a way to update Blob storage and I could not get the Signature.

My account is: configuat.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What is the signature you are looking for? And what do you mean by updating Blob storage?

Comment: I am looking for signature to access Blob storage. Under this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx -, there are web services that azure provides us with. I want to use PUT BLOB (REST API). 
But I could not see why my Authorization key is always refused.

POSTMAN client says this 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
<Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Value Authorization header.RequestId:07353855-392b-471e-ab2f-b5046862b1
Time:2014-02-28T08:55:42.1654202Z</Message>
</Error>

Comment: I see, so authentication is failing. How do you sign your requests?

Comment: Inside POSTMAN there are Headers and Value. I sent to windows azure x-ms-date, x-ms-version, x-ms-blob-type, Authorization and configuat, but every time I get result as I already show in upper comment.

Comment: It looks like your authentication signature did not match what server generated. I added an answer for more information on how to generate the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Shared Key authentication, the Authorization header must be in a specific format and must be able to authenticate your request with a matching signature. For more information on this topic, please see our MSDN article [Authentication for the Windows Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx).

Comment: It is explained in the "Constructing the Signature String" section, but it might not be easy if you are manually crafting your request. Can you instead use a tool to upload your blob? For example, AzCopy can help with this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx

Comment: Account Key is associated with your account and can be found in Windows Azure Portal. Please see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-storage-account/ for more information.

Comment: I know my account key, but when I put it in POSTMAN header - it doesn't pass the authentification. 
I want to use POSTMAN, because all of my team is using it.

Comment: You should not have your account key directly in the header. Please see the "Encoding the Signature" section in the article I shared. Your account key is the key to the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm.